# the Url with parameter Id in production is not found in Angular

Tags: angular

i have a transaction component that takes an id path variable **(transaction/id)** in local server (4200) it works fine.. but when i do 
`ng build` and put the dist in an apache server.. this page gives not found.. 
it puts wrong path to the scripts loaded in `index.html` ... it appends the name of the cmponent to the path of the resources...

when i remove the id from the path in `app-routing` module and get **/transaction** it works fine

the `app-routing` module includes :

```
{ 
  path: "transaction/:id", component: TransactionComponent 
}
```

and i get the id like this

```
+this._route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')
```

it raises exceptions in the console that the resources are not found...

Comment: Have you have changed `the base href` in `index.html`?

Comment: no it's <base href="." /> 
the thing is : all sidebar links works fine... there is no problem in the context root... the problem happens with the component having path variable

Comment: generally by default in Angular app `index.html` has `<base href="/">`

Comment: Maybe the component name is appended to path of resources as no `/` is present in `base href` tag.

Answer (score 0):

just try out to get router's id parameter like this ,

1. first `import { ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router'` in your component .ts file.
2. then in your components constructor `private activatedroute: ActivatedRoute`
3. and simply get your router params id like this in your ngOnInit() ,

   `let Id = this.activatedroute.snapshot.params.id`

may be its works for you !

Comment: i'm already using AvtivatedRoute... (this._route) is an AvtivatedRoute instance